# Asking for Training Fees

Tags: training

I met a person on a Forum who asked me if I can provide an online programming training. I never had this experience so I said yes. As we both are from different countries, he skipped the first session 2-3 times and later apologized.

I forgave him and asked if we can start it again. We have started it this week and we have covered 2 sessions of training till date.

I am new to this so not sure when is the right time for me to ask for the training fees. And how should I ask for it without sounding greedy or anything. I am just worried that, he should not just vanish after finishing it up as I do not have any deal proof of the training course I am providing.

Am I being informal? What is the right way to provide online training? Let me know if any one has any similar experiences.

Comment: Did you negotiate a rate for training fees?  Does your student realise that you intend to charge them?

Comment: @JaneS Yes. We have discussed and have already decided the training charges. Its on hourly basis.

Comment: How frequently are you conducting training?  You could invoice after each session, or on a weekly, fortnightly or monthly basis.  This should have been outlined in your initial agreement.

Comment: @JaneS That's were I was not professional enough. We just discussed how much I am going to charge and he agreed without any formal written/documented agreement. We have covered 1Hour(Day1) and 2Hours(Day2) till date. That's it. I have my next session tomorrow.

Comment: For this sort of informal arrangement, what you could do is simply wait until he pays you before continuing with the next training session. The fact that he pays you shows his agreement of your terms. If he doesn't pay you for the last training session then you're out 1-2 hours (the length of a training session) but you can simply refuse to do any further training sessions until you receive payment.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would send him a paypal invoice or something similar before each session.

Alternatively bill him after each session.

This is pretty common practice for consultant type jobs with no prior business relationship, get paid at each step.

You have zero recourse otherwise in recovering what is owed that I can see.

Comment: This is a good idea but I reside in a country where PayPal won't work. There is only a single way i.e. NEFT. Anyway, this helps. I will plan something like this next session onwards.